# Error al cargar los estilos en el navegador de los SmarTv

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer

Hola tengo unos estilos css pero en el navegador de un tv no me estan funcionando. he intentando varias opciones pero ninguna me funciona...

miren mis estilos :

```
.content{
  display:-webkit-box; 
  display:-webkit-flex; 
  display:-ms-flexbox; 
  display:flex; 
  justify-content:center; 
  align-items:center; 
  width:50vw; height:50vh; 
  overflow:hidden;
}
.content-box{
  display:flex; 
  justify-content:center; 
  align-items:center; 
  width:90%; 
  height:70%;
}
.content-box__img{
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
  box-sizing:border-box; 
  margin:0 auto; 
  text-align:left; 
  width:200px;
}
.content-box__text{
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
}
.p_name{
  font-size:1.2em;
}
.img_picture{
  max-width:max-content;
}
```

y esta es a vista :

```
<div class="carousel-fade carousel-birthdays">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="cum-item">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content-box">
          <div class=".content-box__img">
            <img class="img_picture" src="admin/images/123/123.png">
          </div>
          <div class="content-box__text">
            <p class="p_name">Stefany </p>
            <p class="p_surname">Sierra Restrepo</p>
            <p class="p_job">Auxiliar de enfermeria</p>
            <p class="p_date">25 de enero</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

No se si necesiten todo el codigo fuente ya que hay solo les mostre la seccion que estoy intentando organizar.

Esta es la url del sitio por si lo quieren probar.
http://seadoglabs.com/iq/pru/

Así se ve en el tv:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se ve en el pc:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigos completos**********

MAIN.CSSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

html  {
      overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
body {margin:0px; font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif; color:#fff;}
.pantalla {height:100vh; width:100%;}

.fel{font-weight:200;}
.fl{font-weight:300;}
.fr{font-weight:400;}
.fsb{font-weight:600;}
.fb{font-weight:700;}

.mt30{margin-top:30px;}
.fleft{float:left;}
.txc{text-align:center;}

.mod-right{background:#154482; width:34%; height:100vh;}
.mod-left{ height:100vh; width:66%; background:#ddd;}
.video iframe{position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width: 66%;height: 59%;}
.cumeve{width:100%; height:41vh; position:absolute; bottom:0;}
.cumple{ background:#1888c8; height:41vh; width:33%;}
.events{ background:#ff25b0; height:41vh; width:33%;}
.logo{ width:100%; text-align:right; padding:30px 30px 0 0;}
.title-cumple{background:#299fd8; font-size:25px; text-align:center; line-height:64px; }
.title-events{background:#e71a9d; font-size:25px; text-align:center; line-height:64px; }
.iq-todos{background:#ff25b0; margin-top:30px;}
.notas-t{font-size:30px; text-align:center; margin:150px 0 20px;}
.todos-t {font-size:30px;  text-align: center; line-height:50px; width:100%; border-bottom:1px solid #50c1d8; border-top:1px solid #50c1d8;}
.flecha{background:#e71a9d; text-align:right; width:4%}
.des-todos{font-size:20px; padding: 14px 10px; line-height:22px; width:52%; background:#ff25b0; height:91px;}
.desc{font-size:20px; padding:20px; line-height:25px;}
.gal{margin-top:0px;}
.item-t{text-align:center;  padding:15px 0; font-size:25px; background:#1888c8; }
.link{color:#FC0; text-align:center; font-size:25px;}


.container-fluid {padding:0;}
.row{margin:0;}
.col, .col-1, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-auto { padding:0; border:1px solid;}
.mod-der{background:#154482; height:100vh;}
.input-small{width: 150px !important;}/* intentar con porcentaje*/
.sin-border{border-color: transparent !important;background:transparent !important;}





.fhour{position:absolute; bottom:20px; right:30px;}
#date{ font-size:20px !important; }
#clock{font-size:38px !important; margin-top:-8px;}
.mod-izq{background:#ddd;}
.video{ background:#09C;}

@media tv {
.content{display:-webkit-box; display:-webkit-flex; display:-ms-flexbox; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; width:50vw; height:50vh; overflow:hidden;}
.content-box{display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; width:90%; height:70%;}
.content-box__img{width:100%; height:100%; box-sizing:border-box; margin:0 auto; text-align:left; width:200px;}
.content-box__text{width:100%; height:100%;}
.p_name{font-size:1.2em;}
.img_picture{max-width:max-content;}
}




/*CARRUSEL*/
.carousel-item{}
.carousel {position: absolute !important;}
.not-item{width:90%; background:#265ea9; height:auto; margin:0 auto;}
.cum-item {width:90%; height:90%; margin:0 auto;}
.img-cum{border:7px solid #fff; margin-top: 10px;}
.img-l{width:100%;  }
.name{font-size:26px; margin-top:35px; margin-left:10px; line-height:25px; width:50%; }
.cargo{font-size:18px;  margin-left:10px;  margin-top:20px: line-height:25px; }
```

INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="content">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="google" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name=”robots” content=”noimageindex”>
<title>IQ para todos</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

<script>


 // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(idVideo) {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          playerVars : {
                listType:'playlist',
                list: 'PLn5lEmVWb0R-YLCFw2FYwptEqkZMRheFN',
                loop: true
            },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == 0) {
          player.loadVideoById({videoId:'qUGY0rWZu4Q'});
          alert("acabo");
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }






var inicio =true;
function startTime() {
  if(inicio) {

    inicio=false;
    realizaProceso();
  }

    var today = new Date();
    var hr = today.getHours();
    var min = today.getMinutes();
    var sec = today.getSeconds();
    ap = (hr < 12) ? "<span>a.m.</span>" : "<span>p.m.</span>";
    hr = (hr == 0) ? 12 : hr;
    hr = (hr > 12) ? hr - 12 : hr;
    //Add a zero in front of numbers<10
    hr = checkTime(hr);
    min = checkTime(min);
    sec = checkTime(sec);
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hr + ":" + min  + " " + ap;

    var months = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];
    var days = ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'];
    var curWeekDay = days[today.getDay()];
    var curDay = today.getDate();
    var curMonth = months[today.getMonth()];
    var curYear = today.getFullYear();
    var date = curWeekDay+", "+curDay+" "+curMonth+" "+curYear;
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;
    //validarCambios();
    var time = setTimeout(function(){ startTime() }, 500);



}
setInterval("validarCambios();", 10000);
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}




function validarCambios(){
  var parametros = {};
  $.ajax({
    data:  parametros,
    url:   'controller/index.php',
    type:  'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
         console.log(request);
         console.log(status);
         console.log(error);
    },
    success:  function (response) {
      if(response.estado['id']>$("body").data("id")) {
       // $("body").attr("data-id", response.estado['id']);
        //realizaProceso();
        location.reload();
      }
    } 
  });
}

function realizaProceso(){
  var parametros = {};
  $.ajax({
    data:  parametros,
    url:   'controller/index.php',
    type:  'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
         console.log(request);
         console.log(status);
         console.log(error);
    },
    success:  function (response) {

      /*var randomColor = '#'+ ('000000' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)).slice(-6);
      $('#resultado').css({
        'background-color' : randomColor,
      });*/
      $("body").attr("data-year", response.estado['year']);
      $("body").attr("data-month", response.estado['month']);
      $("body").attr("data-day", response.estado['day']);
      $("body").attr("data-hour", response.estado['hour']);
      $("body").attr("data-minute", response.estado['minute']);
      $("body").attr("data-id", response.estado['id']);
      $(".loader").hide();
      $(".carousel-congratulations").html(response.congratulations);
      $(".title-cumple").html(response.titleBirthday);
      $(".carousel-birthdays").html(response.birthdays);
      $(".title-events").html(response.titleEvent);
      $(".carousel-events").html(response.events);
      window.history.pushState("", "", '/iq/pru/');
    }
  });


}




</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">
<div class="pantalla">
  <div class="mod-left fleft">
    <div class="video fleft">
      <!--<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RQMAn68hvYY?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
      <div id="player"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cumeve">
      <div class="cumple fleft">
        <div class="title-cumple" > <span class="fel">Feliz</span> Cumpleaños</div>
        <div class="cont-cumple">

          <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
            <div class="carousel-fade carousel-birthdays">
            </div>
            <!-- AQUI VAN LOS CUMPLEAÑOS-->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="events fleft">
        <div class="title-events"> <span class="fel">Próximos </span>Eventos</div>
        <div class="content-events">
          <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="6200">
            <div class="carousel-fade carousel-events">
              <!-- AQUI VAN LOS EVENTOS -->

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mod-right fleft">
    <div class="logo"><img src="admin/images/logo-iq.png" width="200" height="42" /></div>
    <div class="mt30">
      <div class="todos-t fleft">IQ para todos
        <div class="gal">
          <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="8350">
            <div class="carousel-fade carousel-congratulations">
            <!-- AQUI VAN LAS FELICITACIONES -->


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fhour">
      <div id="clockdate">
        <div class="clockdate-wrapper">
          <div id="date"></div>
          <div id="clock"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js" ></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

INDEX.PHP

```
<?php
//fecha del dia de hoy
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');
$hoy = getdate();
$day=$hoy['mday'];
$month=$hoy['mon'];
$year=$hoy['year'];
// Conectando, seleccionando la base de datos
include_once "con.php";
$con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM multimedia WHERE id= ?;");
$sentencia->execute([1]);
$picture = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$titleBirthday = "";
$titleEvent = "";

$sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM binnacle ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;");
$sentencia->execute([1]);
$changes = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM congratulations ORDER BY id ASC;");
$sentencia->execute([1]);
$result = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$estado ="active";
$congratulations = "<div class='container'>";
/*$congratulations = '<div class="carousel-item '.$estado.'">';
$congratulations .= '<div class="not-item">';
$congratulations .= '<img src="admin/images/congratulation/'.$picture->congratulation.'" />';
$congratulations .= '</div></div>';*/
$contador=0;
//$estado="";
foreach($result as $fila) {
    $congratulations .= '<div class="carousel-item '.$estado.'" style="background: transparent;">';
    $estado="";
    $col_image=($fila->image==NULL) ? "default.png" : "felicitaciones/homenajeado".$fila->id."/".$fila->image ;
    $col_title=$fila->title;
    $col_detail=$fila->detail;
    $congratulations .= '<div class="card" style="background: transparent;">';
    $congratulations .= '<div class="card-body">';
    if (!( $col_title==="<!--empty-->"))
        $congratulations .= '<p class="card-title">'.$col_title.'</p>';
    if (!( $col_detail==="<!--empty-->"))
        $congratulations .= '<p class="card-card-text">'.$col_detail.'</p>';
    $congratulations .= '<div class="img-cum fleft sin-border"><img class="img-l" src="admin/images/'.$col_image.'" style="'.$fila->css.'"/></div>';
    $congratulations .= '</div></div></div>';
    $contador++;
}
$congratulations .= '</div>';

$sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM birthdays WHERE day= ? AND month= ?;");
$sentencia->execute([$day, $month]);
$result = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$birthdays = "";
$estado ="active";
$contador=0;
foreach($result as $fila) {
    $birthdays .= '<div class="carousel-item '.$estado.'">';
    $estado="";
    $birthdays .= '<div class="cum-item">';
    $col_image=($fila->image==NULL) ? "default.png" : $fila->id."/".$fila->image ;
    $col_name=$fila->name;
    $col_surname=$fila->surname;
    $col_job=$fila->job;
    $col_month = strftime("%B", DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $fila->month)->getTimestamp()); 
    /*$birthdays .= '<div class="img-cum fleft sin-border"><img class="img-l" src="admin/images/'.$col_image.'" /></div>';
    $birthdays .= '<div class="col sin-border">';
    $birthdays .= '<div class="row">';
    $birthdays .= '<div class="name fleft">'.$col_name.'<br/>'.$col_surname.'</div></div>';
    $birthdays .= '<div class="row">';
    $birthdays .= '<div class="cargo fel "> '.$col_job.'</div>';
    $birthdays .= '<div class="cargo fel"></br> '.$fila->day.' de '.$col_month.'</div>';
    $birthdays .= '</div></div></div></div>';*/

    $birthdays .= '<div class="content">';
        $birthdays .= '<div class="content-box">';
            $birthdays .= '<div class=".content-box__img">';
            $birthdays .= '<img class="img_picture" src="admin/images/'.$col_image.'" />';
            $birthdays .= '</div>';
            $birthdays .= '<div class="content-box__text">';
            $birthdays .= '<p class="p_name">'.$col_name.'</p>';
            $birthdays .= '<p class="p_surname">'.$col_surname.'</p>';
            $birthdays .= '<p class="p_job">'.$col_job.'</p>';
            $birthdays .= '<p class="p_date">'.$fila->day.' de '.$col_month.'</p>';
            $birthdays .= '</div>';
        $birthdays .= '</div>';
    $birthdays .= '</div>';
    $contador++;
}
$titleBirthday = ' <span class="fel">Feliz</span> Cumpleaños';
if($contador==0) {
    $suiche = 0;
    $titleBirthday = ' <span class="fel">Proximo</span> Cumpleaños';
    $sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM birthdays ORDER BY month ASC, day ASC;");
    $sentencia->execute([1]);
    $result = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $birthdays = "";
    $estado ="active";
    foreach($result as $fila) {
        if ($contador==0)  {
            if ($fila->month == $month)  {
                if($fila->day > $day) {
                    $contador ++;
                }
            } else {
                if($fila->month > $month) {
                    $contador ++;
                }
            }
            if($contador==1) {
                $col_image=($fila->image==NULL) ? "default.png" : $fila->id."/".$fila->image ;
                $col_name=$fila->name;
                $col_surname=$fila->surname;
                $col_job=$fila->job;
                $col_month = strftime("%B", DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $fila->month)->getTimestamp()); 
                $birthdays .= '<div class="carousel-item '.$estado.'">';
                $estado="";
                $birthdays .= '<div class="content">';
                    $birthdays .= '<div class="content-box">';
                        $birthdays .= '<div class="content-box__img">';
                            $birthdays .= '<img class="img_picture" src="admin/images/'.$col_image.'"/>';
                        $birthdays .= '</div>';
                        $birthdays .= '<div class="content-box__text">';
                            $birthdays .= '<p class="p_name">'.$col_name." ".$col_surname."</p>";
                            $birthdays .= $col_job;
                            $birthdays .= $fila->day.' de '.$col_month;
                        $birthdays .= '</div>';
                    $birthdays .= '</div>';
                $birthdays .= '</div>';


            }
        }
    }
    /*$sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM birthdays WHERE day= ? AND month= ?;");
    $sentencia->execute([$day, $month]);
    $result = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $birthdays = "";
    $estado ="active";
    foreach($result as $fila) {
        $birthdays .= '<div class="carousel-item '.$estado.'">';
        $estado="";
        $birthdays .= '<div class="cum-item">';
        $col_image=($fila->image==NULL) ? "default.png" : $fila->id."/".$fila->image ;
        $col_name=$fila->name;
        $col_surname=$fila->surname;
        $col_job=$fila->job;
        $col_month = strftime("%B", DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $fila->month)->getTimestamp()); 
        $birthdays .= '<div class="img-cum fleft sin-border"><img class="img-l" src="admin/images/'.$col_image.'" /></div>';
        $birthdays .= '<div class="col sin-border">';
        $birthdays .= '<div class="row">';
        $birthdays .= '<div class="name fleft">'.$col_name.'<br/>'.$col_surname.'</div></div>';
        $birthdays .= '<div class="row">';
        $birthdays .= '<div class="cargo fel "> '.$col_job.'</div>';
        $birthdays .= '<div></br></br></br> '.$fila->day.' de '.$col_month.'</div>';
        $birthdays .= '</div></div></div></div>';
    }*/
    /*
    $sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM cont ents WHERE name = ? AND state = ?;");
    $sentencia->execute(["birthdays", 1]);
    $result = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $estado ="active";

    foreach($result as $fila) { 
        $titleBirthday = $fila->title;
        $birthdays .= '<div class="carousel-item '.$estado.'">';
        $estado="";
        $col_content=$fila->content;
        $birthdays .= '<div class="cum-item">';
        $birthdays .= '<div class="cargo fel "> '.$col_content.'</div>';
        $birthdays .= '</div></div>';
    }
    */
}

$sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE year = ?");
$sentencia->execute([$year]);
$result = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$estado ="active";
$contador=0;
foreach($result as $fila) {
    if( ( ($fila->month == $month) && ($fila->day > $day) ) || ($fila->month > $month) ) {
        $events .= '<div class="carousel-item '.$estado.'">';
        $estado="";
        $events .= '<div class="event-item">';
        $events .= '<div class="row">';
        $col_name = $fila->name;
        $col_description = $fila->description;
        $col_city = $fila->city;
        $col_place = $fila->place;
        $col_day = $fila->day;
        $col_month = strftime("%B", DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $fila->month)->getTimestamp()); 
        $col_month = ucwords(strtolower($col_month));
        $col_hour = strftime("%I", DateTime::createFromFormat('H', $fila->hour)->getTimestamp());
        //$col_minute = strftime("%M", DateTime::createFromFormat('i', $fila->minute)->getTimestamp());
        $col_minute = strlen($fila->minute)==1 ? "0".$fila->minute : $fila->minute;
        $col_format = DateTime::createFromFormat("H", $fila->hour);
        $col_format = $col_format->format("a");
        $events .= '<div class="card sin-border">';
        $events .= '<div class="card-body">';
        $events .= '<div class="col sin-border"><h3 class="text-truncate text-center">'.$col_day.'<small> '.$col_month.'</small></h3></div>';
        $events .= '</div></div>';
        $events .= '<div class="col sin-border">';
        $events .= '<div class="card sin-border" style="border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .10) !important;">';
        $events .= '<div class="card-body">';
        $events .= '<h3 class="card-title text-left">'.$col_name.'</h3>';
        //$events .= '<p class="card-text text-left"> Ciudad: '.$col_city.'</p>';
        $events .= '<p class="card-text text-left">Lugar: '.$col_place.'</p>';
        $events .= '<p class="card-text text-left">Hora: '.$col_hour.':'.$col_minute.' '.$col_format.'</p>';
        $events .= '<p class="card-text text-left"><small>Interesados escribir a info@iqinterquirofanos.co</small></p>';
        $events .= '</div></div></div></div></div></div>';
        $contador++;
    }
}
$titleEvent = ' <span class="fel">Próximos</span> Eventos';
if($contador==0) {
    $sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM contents WHERE name = ? AND state = ?;");
    $sentencia->execute(["events", 1]);
    $result = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $estado ="active";

    foreach($result as $fila) { 
        $titleEvent = $fila->title;
        $events .= '<div class="carousel-item '.$estado.'">';
        $estado="";
        $col_content=$fila->content;
        $events .= '<div class="cum-item">';
        $events .= '<div class="cargo fel "> '.$col_content.'</div>';
        $events .= '</div></div>';
    }
}

//echo $congratulations.$birthdays.$events;
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

//Guardamos los datos en un array
$datos = array(
'estado' => $changes,
'wedewdwede' => $changes,
'congratulations' => $congratulations,
'birthdays' => $birthdays,
'events' => $events,
'titleBirthday' => $titleBirthday,
'titleEvent' => $titleEvent
);
//Devolvemos el array pasado a JSON como objeto
echo json_encode($datos, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

?>
```

Les agradecería cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar

Comment: En la web de samsung hablan de un simulador de TV puedes probar: https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/web-inspector
En FF encontré una opción para simular ser una impresora, quizás puedes simular ser una TV...

Comment: Los SmartTv usan navegadores muy antiguos, por lo general son algo obsoletos así que yo probaría usar estilos CSS no tan modernos o librerías retrocompatibles.